# How to make a section sticky for several seconds and then sticky for all time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In the website - right panel has three ads, what I want - there should be 3 ads top two ads should be fixed for a few seconds and then third ad should be sticky for a long time.
I am using this code, in which third ad i.e. second section of the ad is sticky when scroll reaches to its position,

```
<div class="right-panel">
    <div id="adsection1">
        <!--ad1-->
        <br/>
        <!--ad2-->
    </div>
    <div id="adsection2" style="width: 300px; height: 600px;">
        <div id="abc_ad1">
            <!--ad3-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
    var adElem = document.getElementById('adsection2');
    window.onscroll = function () {
    var rect = adElem.getBoundingClientRect();
    adElem.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
    adElem.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
    document.getElementById('abc_ad1').style.width = rect.width + 'px';
    document.getElementById('abc_ad1').style.height = rect.height + 'px';
    if (rect.top <= 0) {
    document.getElementById('abc_ad1').style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById('abc_ad1').style.top = "0";
    document.getElementById('abc_ad1').style.zIndex = "2147483647";
    } else {
    document.getElementById('abc_ad1').style.position = "";
    document.getElementById('abc_ad1').style.top = "";
    document.getElementById('abc_ad1').style.zIndex = "";
    }
    };
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Consider the right section on this link (I want to design just like it), `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_blockchain/python_blockchain_client_class.htm`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need JavaScript in order to achieve described effect. 
The trick is to properly format your HTML layout - it also means to divide it in appropriate parts, so that you have a right parent for a sticky element.

Side note: I use divs for the sake of simplicity of an example, but in the real life app you should opt for semantic HTML.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  height:200%;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  height: 100%;
  width:50%;
  float: left;
}

#main {
  background: linear-gradient(#58668b, #ffffff);
}

#ads {
 position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color:#bdeaee;
}

#header {
  height:30px;
  background-color: #29a8ab;
}

#footer {
  height:100px;
  background-color: #651e3e;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.top-section {
  height: 25%;
}

.top-section div {
  height: 45%;
  background-color:#ffcc5c;
}

.top-section div:not(:last-child)  {
  margin-bottom:10%;
}

.bottom-section {
  height: 30%;
  background-color: #ff6f69;
  margin-top: 12%;
}

.sticky-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
   <div id="main" class="col"><p>Main Content</p></div>
   <div id="ads" class="col">
     <div class="sticky-content">
       <div class="top-section">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
     <div class="bottom-section"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```